# Programar notificação android

Tags: android, android-notification

Meu aplicativo mostra notificação quando abre, mas eu não queria que mostrasse a notificação toda hora que abrisse o aplicativo, estava querendo mostrar ela uma vez por dia ou ate varias vezes, com os horários específicos. Vou colocar como estou fazendo para mostrar a notificação:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String somString = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.notification_ring_key), "DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI");
    Log.e("tag1",somString);
    Uri somUri = Uri.parse(somString);
    int notificationId = 001;

    Intent viewIntent = new Intent(this, Configuracoes.class);
    viewIntent.putExtra("1", "2");
    PendingIntent viewPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setContentTitle("")
                    .setContentText("Que tal da uma olhada nas suas tarefas agora?")
                    .setSound(somUri)//RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
                    //.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                    .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent);
    boolean result = prefs.getBoolean(getString(R.string.vibrar_key), true);
    if(result) {
        notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
    }

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);


    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Achei isso na internet

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 06);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am =(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

ele cria um alarme em uma Activity na hora especificada, queria saber se tem como ao invés de criar uma Activity tem como só chamar a notificação acima

Comment: Em que método esse código está localizado? Eu creio que seja no `onCreate()`, mas posso estar errado.

Comment: sim, ´onCreate()`

Comment: Então esse é o motivo dele fazer uma notificação sempre que abre o aplicativo. Para fazer as notificações apenas em horários especificos, não sei dizer como.

Você pode fazer o `notificationBuilder` e o `notificationManager` objetos da activity, e então executar o build das notifications em métodos específicos.

Comment: que era por esse motivo eu sabia , mais não to sabendo fazer por hora especifica, vi algo de AlarmManager mais não entendi como utilizar

Answer (score 1):

**Fonte:** https://dhimitraq.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/using-intentservice-with-alarmmanager-to-schedule-alarms/

**Github:** https://github.com/CS-Worcester/TaskButler

---

Você precisa criar um serviço para executar as suas requisições em segundo plano e não deve colocar dentro do método Oncreate(), o seu código de notificação. Talvez isto esteja acontecendo.

Aconselho a você registrar dois BroadcastReceivers, e um service e também obter permissão para usar o wakelock, obtendo sinal Boot_Completed.

---

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<application>
     <receiver android:name=".service.OnBootReceiver" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>

     <receiver android:name=".service.OnAlarmReceiver" >
     </receiver>

     <service android:name=".service.TaskButlerService" >
     </service>
</application>
```

---

Este é um BroadcastReceiver para o ONBOOT completo, usado para reagendar alarmes com o AlarmManager. Há apenas 2 linhas de código no método OnReceive(), que é devido ao seu próprio OnReceive() ser necessariamente curto. A primeira linha adquire um  wakelock parcial para manter a CPU em execução, enquanto a nossa IntentService está em execução.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * BroadCastReceiver para android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
 * passa toda a responsabilidade para TaskButlerService.
 * @author Dhimitraq Jorgji
 *
 */
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        WakefulIntentService.acquireStaticLock(context); //acquire a partial WakeLock
        context.startService(new Intent(context, TaskButlerService.class)); //start TaskButlerService
    }
}
```

---

IntentService é minha maneira favorita de fazer as coisas em segundo plano. Normalmente eu não ponho IntentService diretamente, e eu sugiro que você faça o mesmo; definir um método sincronizado para adquirir um wakelock antes de continuar com o que você precisa realizar.

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PowerManager;

/**
 * Acquires a partial WakeLock, allows TaskButtlerService to keep the CPU alive
 * until the work is done.
 * @author Dhimitraq Jorgji
 *
 */
public class WakefulIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final String
    LOCK_NAME_STATIC="edu.worcester.cs499summer2012.TaskButlerService.Static";;
    public static final String
    LOCK_NAME_LOCAL="edu.worcester.cs499summer2012.TaskButlerService.Local";
    private static PowerManager.WakeLock lockStatic=null;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock lockLocal=null;

    public WakefulIntentService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
     / **
     * Para Adquirir um wakelock estático, é preciso também chamar esta dentro da classe
     * Que chama StartService ()
     * 
     * /
    public static void acquireStaticLock(Context context) {
        getLock(context).acquire();
    }

    synchronized private static PowerManager.WakeLock getLock(Context context) {
        if (lockStatic==null) {
            PowerManager
            mgr=(PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            lockStatic=mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                    LOCK_NAME_STATIC);
            lockStatic.setReferenceCounted(true);
        }
        return(lockStatic);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        PowerManager mgr=(PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        lockLocal=mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                LOCK_NAME_LOCAL);
        lockLocal.setReferenceCounted(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, final int startId) {
        lockLocal.acquire();
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        getLock(this).release();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        lockLocal.release();
    }
}
```

---

Agora podemos simplesmente herdar o WakeFulIntentService , e fazer todo o nosso trabalho com um método simples onHandleIntent(Intent). O método pode ser chamado a partir de qualquer lugar em seu programa e ele vai cuidar de tudo em um plano de fundo como qualquer Service, também de forma segura, uma vez que detém uma wakelock até que o método termine no ponto em que ele retorne o fechamento.

```
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Intent;

import edu.worcester.cs499summer2012.database.TasksDataSource;
import edu.worcester.cs499summer2012.task.Task;

 / **
 * Uma IntentService cuida da criação de alarmes para Task Butler
 * Para lembrar o usuário de eventos
 * author Dhimitraq Jorgji
 *
 * /
public class TaskButlerService extends WakefulIntentService{

    public TaskButlerService() {
        super("TaskButlerService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        TasksDataSource db = TasksDataSource.getInstance(this); //get access to the instance of TasksDataSource
        TaskAlarm alarm = new TaskAlarm();

        List<Task> tasks = db.getAllTasks(); //Get a list of all the tasks there
        for (Task task : tasks) {
            // Cancelar alarme existente
            alarm.cancelAlarm(this, task.getID());

            //alarmes de aviso
            if(task.isPastDue()){
                alarm.setReminder(this, task.getID());
            }

            //alarmes de repetição
            if(task.isRepeating() && task.isCompleted()){
                task = alarm.setRepeatingAlarm(this, task.getID());
            }

            //alarmes regulares
            if(!task.isCompleted() && (task.getDateDue() >= System.currentTimeMillis())){
                alarm.setAlarm(this, task);
            }
        }
        super.onHandleIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

---

Neste ponto, você só precisa de um BroadcastReceiver para receber seus alarmes .

```
package edu.worcester.cs499summer2012.service;

import edu.worcester.cs499summer2012.database.TasksDataSource;
import edu.worcester.cs499summer2012.task.Task;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * BroadCastReceiver for Alarms, displays notifications as it receives alarm
 * and then starts TaskButlerService to update alarm schedule with AlarmManager
 * @author Dhimitraq Jorgji
 *
 */
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        WakefulIntentService.acquireStaticLock(context); //adquirindo WakeLock

        //enviando notificação com taskID
        NotificationHelper notification = new NotificationHelper();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        int id = bundle.getInt(Task.EXTRA_TASK_ID);
        TasksDataSource db = TasksDataSource.getInstance(context);
        Task task = db.getTask(id);

        if(task.hasFinalDateDue() || task.getPriority() == Task.URGENT){
            notification.sendPersistentNotification(context, task); // Básica notificação
        } else {
            notification.sendBasicNotification(context, task); //Básica notificação
        }

        context.startService(new Intent(context, TaskButlerService.class)); //iniciando TaskButlerService
    }
}
```